# How to resolve the flow error : You can say myField, myField.myChoice.selected, or myField.myChoice.input when using 2 columns in screen flow

Tags: lightning, visual-workflow

When using a Screen Flow for Order creation, on the record creation screen flow is throwing an error "Could not resolve 'xxxxx'.You can say myField, myField.myChoice.selected, or myField.myChoice.input".
The error is occurring only if the flow used with 2 columns, for 1 column it's working fine. But as per the requirement we need to show it in dual column layout. 
We used custom button in Order with flow url as "/flow/OrderFlow?flowLayout=twoColumn&contactId={!Contact.Id}&caseId={!Case.Id}"
Please suggest any possible work around (using flow only) if it's a known issue.

Comment: This actually happened in Summer '20 release. We raised a case with Salesforce, and they said it will be fixed in a patch release soon. For the Sandboxes and Prod which are in Spring '20, it's still working fine.

Comment: I am also facing the same error in scratch org. Have not tried it in Prod org. Any update on this ?

Comment: Salesforce had provided the fix in latest patch releases. Now the issue has been resolved @lambad